# Emulate nfs as sdcard : mount --bind <olddir> <mountpoint>

Tags: nfs, block-device

Can I mount  with --bind and change with -t vfat ?

It's not working.

So can I mount an nfs as a blockdevice, then mount it to something else ?

Comment: you may be looking for `nbd` or `iSCSI` rather than `NFS`.  see eg https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119364/222377

Comment: I cant, it's an embedded linux with 32Ko and an SDCard not functionnal.

Answer (score 0):

`mount -bind` is only for duplicating part of the filesystem tree on another place.

If you have access to an image of a filesystem (created e.g. by using `dd if=/dev/sda1 of=/whatever/sda1.img`) then you can do a loop mount of that image, which works by simulating a block device:

```
mount -o loop /whatever/sda1.img /mnt
```

Now the filesystem contained in `/whatever/sda1.img` is available under `/mnt`.

Comment: Thank you, i saw my mistake. It's stupid to change an nfs share to an vfat one.